# Android Listview hide duplicate entries

Tags: android, listview, duplicates, hide

I have a String-Array which has duplicate entries, think of A,B,C,D,E,F,F,G,G,G,G,H,H,H,I,I. The duplicates are needed for other String-arrays to have the same id. However, I do not want the duplicates to appear in the ListView I have it in. I've tried messing around with hashsets, but I couldn't exactly integrate it. Could you guys give me any tips on succeeding?

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle)
{
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);
    lv1=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
    ed=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
    textSearch = new TextView(this);
    textSearch = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textSearch);
    textSearch.setText(SearchHeadText);

    lv1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , searchItems));
    ed.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                      int after) {
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                                  int count) {

            textlength = ed.getText().length();
            arr_sort.clear();
            for (String searchItem : searchItems) {
                if (textlength <= searchItem.length()) {
                    if (ed.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase((String) searchItem.subSequence(0, textlength))) {
                        arr_sort.add(searchItem);
                    }
                }
            }

            lv1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Rest_Search_Monotherapie.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arr_sort));
        }
    });
    lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v,
                                int position, long id) {
//                String a = parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
//                menuID = (int) id;

            a = (String) parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);
            menuID = CheckID(a);

            Toast.makeText(Rest_Search_Monotherapie.this,  a+" "+menuID, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, Pre_Antistolling_Monotherapie_info.class);
                startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can create custom Adapter with HashMap container. Something like this:
`HashMap<String, List<String>>` Key is unic entry and in `List<Strings>` contains duplicates entities. And you can get it ids with formula (key position in sorted key array) + index in `List<String>`

Answer (score 0):

you can use `replaceAll()` with regex for it!